# how to use function in a select block , when the function return a record

Tags: plsql

When my function return a array.(type t_source is a table of number)

```
FUNCTION func_f(p_plan_id NUMBER,
                            p_item_id NUMBER) RETURN t_source IS
    x_source_o t_source;
```

How to use the return array in a select block without use a template value, like:

```
select func_f(plan_id,item_id)(1),func_f(plan_id,item_id)(2) from dual;
```

So anyone know the right way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the function for casting array types:

```
CREATE TYPE phone_book_t AS TABLE OF phone_list_typ;
/
SELECT CAST(COLLECT(phone_numbers) AS phone_book_t) 
   FROM customers;
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions024.htm